# Node.js Express Stopwatch with API to Start/Stop/Reset

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i already have a working (but ugly) solution to this.
I am new to Node.js & Express, working with C# and Powershell most of the time.
I want to have a simple webpage (**localhost:8080/sw**) displaying a **00:00:00 (hh:mm:ss)** Stopwatch timer.
When i call the **localhost:8080/sw?action=toggle**, i want to switch between running/paused stated, and when setting the action to restart, i want to set it back to 0, doesnt matter if its still running or also pauses the timer on 0.

I currently have a really ugly solution that replaces the contents of the sw.html file and the file reloads itself automatically every second.

It would be great if someone could point me in a direction of having it *"in node.js style"*.. . like not text replacing a file.
I dont really know how to execute code from the get-endpoint on the displayed page.
I think an example of how to just change text on a page via an api call would be great. Or do i need some DB for this?

This is my current UGLY solution:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(
    PORT,
    () => console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`)
);

var stopwatchRunning = false;
var curSeconds = 0;
const path = require('path');

app.get('/sw', (req, res) => {
    var content = "";
    const action = req.query.action;
    if(action === 'toggle') {
        stopwatchRunning = !stopwatchRunning;
        console.log("Stopwatch toggled: " + stopwatchRunning);
        startStopwatch();
        res.send('Toggled');
    } else if(action === 'reset') {
        console.log("Stopwatch reset");
        curSeconds = 0;
        res.send('Reset');
    } else {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/sw.html'));
        return;
    }
});

function startStopwatch(){
    if(stopwatchRunning){
        curSeconds++;
        const fs = require('fs')
        fs.writeFile('sw.html', `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1"><h1 style="text-align: center;margin: 100px">${secondsToHms(curSeconds)}</h1>`, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err)
                return
            }
        })
        setTimeout(startStopwatch, 1000);
    }
}

function secondsToHms(d) {
    d = Number(d);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    var hDisplay = h > 10 ? h + ":" : "0" + h + ":";
    var mDisplay = m > 10 ? m + ":" : "0" + m + ":";
    var sDisplay = s > 10 ? s : "0" + s;
    return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
}
```

Comment: Reading the first two guides [from this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps#guides) will help you understand the separation between the server (your app here) and the client (the _displayed page_).

Comment: hm okey, so would the solution be, having a client site that queries the server every few second for the state if the timer should be running?
Or is there also a way to not query every second and have some kind of listener in the client sided js file

Comment: Most of the time, a solution like this would be dependent on the output. Your intent is clearly to output the timer onto the _display_ (UI / Browser). Given that, the entire timer application would usually be executed in the browser with no need for a server.

Comment: To clarify, in your C# apps you are accustomed to _thinking_ about your app as a single _thing_. This implies a single code base. In web development (ASP.NET for instance) there are two code bases - server & client that accomplish different tasks. This simple time task code has no need for a server. Hope that is better explanation.

Comment: thanks for the replies.. the reason i need the server, is because i want to start/stop/restart it via API calls.
I understand the concept of client& server now, but is there also something like a listerner instead of querying every second on the client side? if not, then i will go the route of querying every second, since its atleast a cleaner solution than my current one

Comment: You have three choices. 1. Poll the server (as you suggest by sending queries) 2. Use [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) 3. Use [ServerSentEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the other Comments i came up with a better solution.
It probably still isnt the best, since im still polling, but i couldnt bother to build a websocket for it.
I now seperated client & server side better, but not fully, since i dont need to. But ofc the client could be anywhere, i just put it in the same folder for convenience.

index.js (server-side)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
var cors = require('cors')
const PORT = 8080;
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(
    PORT,
    () => console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`)
);

const stopwatchState = {
    RUNNING: "RUNNING",
    STOPPED: "STOPPED",
    RESET: "RESET"
  };

var currentState = stopwatchState.RUNNING; // basically the next command to do
var runningState = stopwatchState.RUNNING; // store the play/paused state for later

app.get('/stopwatch', (req, res) => {
    var content = "";
    const action = req.query.action;
    if(action === 'toggle') {
        currentState = (currentState === stopwatchState.RUNNING) ? stopwatchState.STOPPED : stopwatchState.RUNNING;
        runningState = currentState;
        console.log("Stopwatch toggled: " + runningState);
        res.send("Stopwatch toggled: " + runningState);
        return;
    } else if(action === 'reset') {
        currentState = stopwatchState.RESET;
        console.log("Stopwatch reset");
        res.send('Stopwatch reset');
        return;
    } else if (action === 'get') {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(currentState));
        currentState = (runningState === stopwatchState.RUNNING) ? stopwatchState.RUNNING : stopwatchState.STOPPED;
    } else {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/Stopwatch/stopwatch.html'));
    }
});
```

stopwatch/stopwatch.html (client side)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stopwatch</title>
    <script>
        var curSeconds = 0;
        var shouldReset = false;
        var currentState = "RUNNING";

        function runTimer() {
            if(shouldReset) {
                curSeconds = 0;
                shouldReset = false;
            } else if(currentState === "RUNNING") {
                curSeconds++;
            } else {
                return;
            }
            setTime(secondsToHms(curSeconds));
        }

        function setTime(currentTimeString) {
            var timeElement = document.getElementById("timer");
            timeElement.innerHTML = currentTimeString;
        }

        function secondsToHms(d) {
            d = Number(d);
            var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
            var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
            var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

            var hDisplay = h >= 10 ? h + ":" : "0" + h + ":";
            var mDisplay = m >= 10 ? m + ":" : "0" + m + ":";
            var sDisplay = s >= 10 ? s : "0" + s;
            return hDisplay + mDisplay + sDisplay; 
        }

        async function getStopwatchState() {
            let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/stopwatch?action=get';
            try {
                let res = await fetch(url);
                currentState = await res.json();
                if(currentState === "RESET") {
                    shouldReset = true;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }

        setInterval(runTimer, 1000);
        setInterval(getStopwatchState, 400);
    </script>
    <style>
        #timer
        {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 100px;
            font-size: 15vw;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="timer">00:00:00</h1>    
</body>
</html>
```